# How can I improve the following code performance to ingest 1 million record /second

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, kafka-python

The following code are ingesting 10k-20k record per second and I want to improve the performance of it. I am reading a json format and ingesting it into database using Kafka. 
-I am running it on the cluster of five nodes with zookeeper and Kafka installed on it.

Can you give me some tips to improve?

```
import os
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool
from kafka.client import KafkaClient
from kafka.producer import SimpleProducer


def process_line(line):
    producer = SimpleProducer(client)
    try:
       jrec = json.loads(line.strip())
       producer.send_messages('twitter2613',json.dumps(jrec))
    except ValueError, e:
                {}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = KafkaClient('10.62.84.35:9092')
    myloop=True
    pool = Pool(30)


    direcToData = os.listdir("/FullData/RowData")
    for loop in direcToData:
        mydir2=os.listdir("/FullData/RowData/"+loop)

        for i in mydir2:
            if  myloop:
                 with open("/FullData/RowData/"+loop+"/"+i) as source_file:
                     # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
                     results = pool.map(process_line, source_file, 30)
```

Comment: Better to post this [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I think.

Comment: are you implementing https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk by hand?

Comment: @Jasper yes. Do you have any suggestions to do it in parallel on multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe import only the fonction that you need form OS. It can be a first optimization.